# IterativeImputer modifies non-missing values apart from the missing ones

Tags: scikit-learn, missing-data, imputation

I used the IterativeImputer from sklearn.impute to impute values in a large dataframe containing many NaNs and one of the columns, which contained two non-zero values (the rest were 0s and NaNs), is now all 0s. What may be the reason for this?

I tried changing some of the parameters of the imputer but it did not work.

Comment: Could you try to make a reproducible example? Like the code in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#iterative-imputer, but then with your data, or a subset of your data that still shows the issue. Note that the code example there rounds the values before printing, which causes values <0.5 to be displayed as 0.